# Fields in Form display in differently because of long label

Tags: html, css

I'm trying everything I can to align these fields.

In wider screens, its display is okay but with smaller screens, the label becomes too long that affects the alignment of the fields.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I'm planning to have them display like this if the screen isn't wide enough:
[image]

My codes so far:

```css
.column-50, .column-100 {
   float: left
}

.column-50 {
   width: 50%
}
.marginbottom-4 {
   margin-bottom: 1.2em
}
```

```html
<div class="column-100 marginbottom-4">
  <div class="column-50" style="padding: 0 0.2em">
    <div>
      <label>LABEL HERE</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-50" style="padding: 0 0.2em">
    <div>
      <label>LONG LABEL GOES HERE</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Already tried playing with padding, vertical-align, justify-content but maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and create runnable code snippets using the snippet option so that answerers can run and copy your snippets and provide the answers.

Comment: where is your CSS? always post a complete executable code in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be using a table

```html
<table style="width: 100px;">
  <tr>
    <td>LABEL HERE</td>
    <td>LONG LABEL GOES HERE</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` and align your items at the bottom using `align-items: end;`

You can play around more with this css property like `center` , `start` etc: [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: end;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div>
      <label>LABEL HERE</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
        <div>
      <label>LONG LABEL GOES HERE</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
```